# .val() is not working and is returning as "on"

Tags: html, jquery, css, web

Why does this happen ? I am not using correct syntax here?

HTML is as below

```
<div id="tasks" value="1" class="1">
<input type="checkbox">
<label>Task has been added</label>
</div>
```

jQuery is as below

```
$("#cButton").click(function () {
        var arr_id = [];
        $(":checkbox:checked").each(function (i) {
            arr_id[i] = $(this).val();
            console.log("$(this).val() : " + $(this).val());
        })
        if (arr_id.length == 0) {
            alert("atleast check one");
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < arr_id.length; i++) {
                $("." + arr_id[i]).remove();
                console.log("Hello");
            }
        }
    });
```

Console O/P is as below

```
$(this).val() : on
```

Comment: Give ```value``` to input (checkbox) not to parent div.

Comment: @tmsbrndz: inside the `.each()`, `$(this)` is the checkbox, not the parent div.

Comment: @Louys Patrice Bessette I mean on html.

Comment: Hoo!!! That is the value he wants!?! I didn't notice that... Good point then.

Comment: Off topic: you *probably* want: `arr_id.push($(this).val())` to have your array setup sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

You placed the `value` attribute on the parent `<div>`... A `<div>` does not have a value. It has to be on the `input`.

The elements which can have a value are <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)</sup>:

- `<button>`
- `<data>`
- `<input>`
- `<li>`
- `<meter>`
- `<option>`
- `<progress>`
- `<param>`

```js
$("#cButton").click(function() {
  var arr_id = [];
  $(":checkbox:checked").each(function(i) {
    arr_id[i] = $(this).val();
    console.log("$(this).val() : " + $(this).val());
  })
  if (arr_id.length == 0) {
    alert("atleast check one");
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr_id.length; i++) {
      $("." + arr_id[i]).remove();
      console.log("Hello");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tasks" class="1">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">
  <label>Task has been added</label>
</div>
<button id="cButton">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get a boolean value from a checkbox input with jQuery is using **prop**: `$(this).prop("checked")`.

> If the value attribute was omitted, the default value for the checkbox is on
> [MDN input type="checkbox"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox)

If you need to use the value of the input you should be placing it inside the input tag. Because you didn't set a value it's taking the default "**on**" when calling `val()` on it.

```js
$("#cButton").click(function () {
        var arr_id = [];
        $(":checkbox:checked").each(function (i) {
            arr_id[i] = $(this).prop("checked");
            console.log($(this).prop("checked"));
        })
        if (arr_id.length == 0) {
            alert("atleast check one");
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < arr_id.length; i++) {
                $("." + arr_id[i]).remove();
                console.log("Hello");
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tasks" value="1" class="1">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Task has been added</label>
</div>
<button id="cButton">Button</button>
```